# Java: Can't connect to database

Tags: java

I am trying to connect to my MSsql 2012 database, but I keep receiving the following error. I have tried looking over tutorial on Internet and kept asking but couldn't receive any answer until now...

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\bosti>cd c:\cazare-full\cazare

c:\cazare-full\cazare>ant deploy
Buildfile: c:\cazare-full\cazare\build.xml

undeploy.tomcat:

delete.files:

drop.old.tables:

BUILD FAILED
c:\cazare-full\cazare\build.xml:46: com.jnetdirect.jsql.u: Failed Logon:com.jnet
direct.jsql.u: Invalid port number:/ url:jdbc:JSQLConnect://sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER;
    at com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.JDBCTask.getConnection(JDBCTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.getConnection(SQLExec.java:942)

    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SQLExec.execute(SQLExec.java:614)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds

c:\cazare-full\cazare>
```

Comment: Is there any other stacktrace to see? Do you have more description of what's happening? If not, then I suggest you to at least use `try-catch` segments and use `e.printStackTrace()` in `catch` to see more details of the exception. With the current info, there could be gazillions of problems happening in your environment.

Comment: Would you show us the jdbc code?  First take is you have the wrong port setup for the driver.

Comment: Can you check the port number you are trying to connect to? Also, can you make sure that db is actually listening on port 1433. After that check to see if the db server is started

Comment: The error message `Invalid port number:/` looks like someone tries to interprete `:/` as a port number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection URLs have a specific form, which is this:

```
jdbc:JSQLConnect://serverName:port/property=value[/property=value]
```

But you use this:

```
url:jdbc:JSQLConnect://sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER;
```

You can follow [this link](http://www.jnetdirect.com/jsqlconnect-technical-reference.html#BuildingConnectionURL) for a few more details; the meat of it is below.

> The general form of the connection URL is
>
> jdbc:JSQLConnect://serverName:port/property=value[/property=value]
>
> where :-
>
> - JSQLConnect (Required) is known as the sub-protocol and is constant.
> - serverName (Required) is the address of the server to connect to. May be a DNS or IP address.  Maybe locallost or 127.0.0.1 for the
>     local machine.
> - Port (Optional) is the port to connect to on serverName. The default is 1433. If you are using the default then there is no need to
>     specify the port (or it's preceeding ':') in the URL.
> - Property (Optional) is one or more option connection properties. See the following section on connection properties for details. Any
>     property from the list may be specified. Properties can be delimited
>     with '/' or '&'.